# Import and use android wheel as number picker

Tags: android, import, numbers, picker

I have a question with this project https://github.com/sephiroth74/AndroidWheel .. I have found more questions like this but its answers were not that i expected. The thing is that I cloned it to Eclipse by using IMPORT -> Clone GIT. Then i clicked project properties and ticked "Is Library" checkbox, so I went to my project, click add, and when androidwheel was selected a lot of errors appeared in my projects. Errors said this:

```
    R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I managed to use devmilcolor library  with my project, so i dont know where is my error :(

I have to say that import android.R is not used!

Please help to identify my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be Project have a wheel.jar file in bin-folder.

^^If you could not find this file. Click [here](http://mfiles.naver.net/158009baaef3f12d04e48fb0886d136dcb9b6a870a/20120615_50_blogfile/kangdaejang_1339719652536_ko49pz_jar/wheel.jar?type=attachment)

this is a jar file.

Comment: Broken link. Can you please confirm this ?